# Selecting a row linked to data in third table

Tags: mysql

I have three tables A ,B ,C

In table A i have a coloumn unit_id

```
unit_id  id 
3456     45678
```

In Table B have two coloumn id and project_id

```
id             project_id
3456           4567
```

In third table C i have again two coloumns

```
project_id     user_id
4567           36547
```

i want a function where i input only the id from table A and it gives me the User_id from table C corresponding to that unit_id

Comment: dang you just changed the question !

Comment: i changed the question as per the answer as it requires a unique value in coloumn A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming every `unit_id` always has a single corresponding `user_id`:

```
SELECT A.`unit_id`, C.`user_id` 
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.`unit_id` = B.`id` 
INNER JOIN C ON B.`project_id` = C.`project_id`
```

**Edit:**

```
SELECT C.`user_id` 
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.`unit_id` = B.`unit_id` 
INNER JOIN C ON B.`project_id` = C.`project_id`
where A.id= [your id]
```

Comment: @Niks if this solves it, then please accept the answer with a Green check mark. That's how we roll here.

Comment: emanuel thanks for the reply but the unit_id in table A is not unique buit Id corresponding to the Unit_id is can you please update accordingly i can also input the id from coloumn A as the input valie to get the desired result

Comment: Nicks - do you mean a user can have multiple units?